# error with ESC key in multiple stacked modal bs3

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an application working fine on bootstrap3 that open various modals once and i want to add another modal over an open modal (i know the issues with multiples modals on bootstrap3).

I find a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/likhi1/wtj6nacd/) that can i use.

The problem appears when the user press the 'ESC' key the modal on bottom is closed! and i want to close the  modal on top.....

Can anyone tell me a clue for open only two modals one front other?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#openBtn').click(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal({
      show: true
    })
  });

  $(document).on({
    'show.bs.modal': function() {
      var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
      $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
      }, 0);
    },
    'hidden.bs.modal': function() {
      if ($('.modal:visible').length > 0) {
        // restore the modal-open class to the body element, so that scrolling works
        // properly after de-stacking a modal.
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(document.body).addClass('modal-open');
        }, 0);
      }
    }
  }, '.modal');
});
```

this is the code that i'm working

your help will be very appreciated!